# How can I get better randomization in my sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, random

I am attempting to get a random bearing, from 0 to 359.9.

```
SET bearing = FLOOR((RAND() * 359.9));
```

I may call the procedure that runs this request within the same while loop, immediately one after the next.  Unfortunately, the randomization seems to be anything but unique. e.g.

Results

> 358.07
>
> 359.15
>
> 357.85

I understand how randomization works, and I know because of my quick calls to the same function, the ticks used to generate the random number are very close to one another.

In any other situation, I would wait a few milliseconds in between calls or reinit my Random object (such as in C#), which would greatly vary my randomness.  However, I don't want to wait in this situation.

How can I increase randomness without waiting?

Comment: From the MySQL docs: "RAND() is not meant to be a perfect random generator. It is a fast way to generate random numbers on demand that is portable between platforms for the same MySQL version."

Comment: You would reinit your random object to solve that the ticks are close together? I don't think you understand how PRNG's work at all...

Comment: @Marc B Exactly -- that's why I'm asking how to do it better! :)

Comment: @Blindy Most likely because the reinit'ing of the object would cause time to pass.  Poor way to do it I suppose.

Comment: @George actually it wouldn't. Plus time passing has nothing to do with generating the next item in the sequence. At all.

Comment: Given that MySQL has a bad RNG, I'd suggest pre-populating a table with numbers read from a real PRNG, like /dev/urandom or whatever's available on your system. Then just iterate through the table for each query. If you refresh this random table at regular intervals, it should be an acceptable replacement for RAND()

Comment: @Blindy Telling me that I don't understand the problem doesn't help me understand how to find a solution.  It only reinforces that I infact do not understand how to solve my problem.  Perhaps you could respond with an answer, sense you seem to have a better grasp of it than I do, in correcting my ignorance of randomization?

Comment: I wouldn't assume that MySQL has a bad PRNG, a simple test shows much better distribution than you are getting.  Are you sure the problem doesn't lie elsewhere?  The numbers you've shown are not the result of the code you've shown (since the numbers haven't been FLOOR'd), and they aren't the output of RAND (since they go up to 360).  Carefully examine the rest of your code (or update the question with the code).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I understand how randomization works, and I know because of my quick calls to the same function, the ticks used to generate the random number are very close to one another.

That's not quite right. Where folks get into trouble is when they re-seed a random number generator repeatedly with the current time, and because they do it very quickly the time is the same and they end up re-seeding the RNG with the same seed. This results in the RNG spitting out the same sequence of numbers each time it is re-seeded.

Importantly, by "the same" I mean *exactly* the same. An RNG is either going to return an identical sequence or a completely different one. A "close" seed won't result in a "similar" sequence. You will either get an identical sequence or a totally different one.

The correct solution to this is not to stagger your re-seeds, but actually to *stop re-seeding* the RNG. You only need to seed an RNG once.

---

Anyways, that is neither here nor there. MySQL's `RAND()` function does not require explicit seeding. When you call `RAND()` without arguments the seeding is taken care of for you meaning you can call it repeatedly without issue. There's no time-based limitation with how often you can call it.

Actually your SQL looks fine as is. There's something missing from your post, in fact. Since you're calling `FLOOR()` the result you get should always be an integer. There's no way you'll get a fractional result from that assignment. You should see integral results like this:

```
187
274
89
345
```

That's what I got from running `SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * 359.9)` repeatedly.

---

Also, for what it's worth `RAND()` will never return 1.0. Its range is 0 ≤ `RAND()` < 1.0. You are safe using 360 vs. 359.9:

```
SET bearing = FLOOR(RAND() * 360);
```

Comment: Thank you, that eliminates the RAND function as my issue.  You are correct, there are other variables in this problem that were not listed.  I will investigate.  Thanks for the tips!